# VBA IF statement not finding indicated marker

Tags: vba, if-statement

There is a moment where the program has t = 1 but my if statement wont find it.

what gives?
Most of the question is code to fully experiment with the issue
What i am trying to do with my if statement is to find when t = whole number integers example 1,2,3,4,5 then do stuff to return other results but i cant find the moments when t= 1 so im stuck

```
    Dim neq As Double
    neq = 2
    Dim e As Double
    e = Exp(1)
    Dim t_int As Integer
    t_int = 5

    '''''COUNTERS
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim colOf As Integer

    '''''EQUATION CONTROL
    Dim h(3) As Double
    Dim n As Double

    '''''EQUATION CONTROL
    Dim u() As Double
    Dim uStar() As Double
    Dim uOld() As Double
    Dim uEx As Double

    '''''EQUATION CONTROL
    Dim f() As Double
    Dim fOld() As Double

    '''''EQUATION CONTROL
    Dim t As Double
    Dim tOld As Double
    Dim tNew As Double

    '''''SIZING ARRAY
    ReDim u(neq)
    ReDim uOld(neq)
    ReDim uStar(neq)
    ReDim f(neq)
    ReDim fOld(neq)

    '''''INITAL VAULES
    h(1) = 0.1
    h(2) = 0.05
    h(3) = 0.025
    u(1) = 2
    u(2) = 0

colOf = 12

For j = 1 To 1
Cells(1, 1 + colOf) = "h(" & j & ") = " & h(j)
Cells(2, 1 + colOf) = "t"
Cells(2, 2 + colOf) = "u(1)"
Cells(2, 3 + colOf) = "u(2)"
Cells(2, 4 + colOf) = "uEx"
For n = 1 To (t_int / h(j))

    tOld = t
    t = tOld + h(j)
    For i = 1 To neq
        uOld(i) = u(i)
    Next i
    For i = 1 To neq
        fOld(i) = fDeriv(uOld, tOld, i)
        uStar(i) = uOld(i) + h(j) * fOld(i)
    Next i
    For i = 1 To neq
        f(i) = fDeriv(uStar, t, i)
        u(i) = uOld(i) + (h(j) * (fOld(i) + f(i))) / 2
    Next i
    i = i - 1
    uEx = 2 * e ^ -t * (Cos((3 ^ 0.5) * t) + ((3 ^ 0.5) ^ -1) * Sin((3 ^ 0.5) * t))

    Cells(n + 2, 1 + colOf) = t
    Cells(n + 2, 2 + colOf) = u(1)
    Cells(n + 2, 3 + colOf) = u(2)
    Cells(n + 2, 4 + colOf) = uEx

    **If t = 1  Then Debug.Print t**

    Next n
colOf = colOf + 5
Next j
```

Comment: `If cint(t) = 1  Then Debug.Print t`

Comment: what does this do?
can you explain why my if statement was not working?
is there a mathematical formula to achieve this result?

Comment: A double can have a floating decimal.  which mean `t` may equal `0.999999998` or `1.0000001` which does not equal `1`.  By using `Cint` we change it to an integer which should round off the decimal.  If tha does not work then use `Round(t,0) = 1` which rounds to the nearest whole number.

Comment: so non of these options are working to pull out when t = 1 or 2 or 3 or ect ect

Comment: before the `if` put `Debug.print t` and see what you are getting.

Comment: im getting the counter of t as you can see t has the values i want but i can't grab them

0.1 
 0.2 
 0.3 
 0.4 
 0.5 
 0.6 
 0.7 
 0.8 
 0.9 
 1 
 1.1 
 1.2 
 1.3 
 1.4 
 1.5 
 1.6 
 1.7 
 1.8 
 1.9 
 2 
 2.1 
 2.2 
 2.3 
 2.4 
 2.5 
 2.6 
 2.7 
 2.8 
 2.9 
 3 
 3.1 
 3.2 
 3.3 
 3.4 
 3.5 
 3.6 
 3.7 
 3.8 
 3.9 
 4 
 4.1 
 4.2 
 4.3 
 4.4 
 4.5 
 4.6 
 4.7 
 4.8 
 4.9 
 5

Comment: Try this `If CInt(t * 10) / 10 = 1 Then Debug.Print t`

Comment: so this gives me it just off by a factor of 10

     If t Mod n = 0 Then Debug.Print t

Comment: so  If CInt(t * 10) / 10 = 1 Then Debug.Print t gives me t at 1 but i need it to give me t @ 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: `If CInt(t * 10) / 10 = CInt(t) Then Debug.Print t`

Comment: Yes this worked.  But can you explain a bit more as to why?

also what is the math that makes this work?

Comment: How would i make this work if i wanted it to find the values associated with 0.5, 1, 1.5, & 2 ?
If CInt(t * 10) / 10 = CInt(t) Then Debug.Print t